# Creating new columns with value names of other columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as shown below.

```
DF =

id  w  R
1   A  L    
2   B  J      
3   C  L,J
```

I now want to create a new column that shows if the value in the column `R`appears in the row.

```
DF2 =

id  w  R    L  J 
1   A  L    1  0 
2   B  J    0  1 
3   C  L,J  1  1
```

I tried this line, but the result wasn't what I wanted:

```
for x in DF.R.unique():
  DF[x]=(DF.R==x).astype(int)


DF2 =

id  w  R    L  J L,J
1   A  L    1  0  0
2   B  J    0  1  0
3   C  L,J  0  0  1
```

What is needed to fix this? The DF is also very big and slow methods won't work.

Comment: get_dummies should do the trick, let me work on an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specific the `sep` , in your example is `,`

```
df.R.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[192]: 
   J  L
0  0  1
1  1  0
2  1  1
```

Comment: lost to saitama once again

Comment: This is undoubtedly a better (and more correct) solution than mine, and should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use pandas' built-in str methods:

```
chars_to_count = ['L', 'J']
for char in chars_to_count:
    DF[char] = DF['R'].str.count(char)
```